# MPFR installation can't find gmp-impl.h

Tags: cygwin, gnu, gmp, mpfr

I'm trying to install MPFR on cygwin.
I successfully ran "./configure --with-gmp-build=../gmp-5.1.3" and it doesn't gave me any error.
But when I ran "make install", it fails and gives following error.

```
In file included from exceptions.c:23:0:
mpfr-impl.h:71:24: fatal error: gmp-impl.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:674: recipe for target `exceptions.lo' failed
make[2]: *** [exceptions.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/d/chamila/mpfr-3.1.2/src'
Makefile:798: recipe for target `install' failed
make[1]: *** [install] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/d/chamila/mpfr-3.1.2/src'
Makefile:385: recipe for target `install-recursive' failed
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

I added gmp location to path as well. What is wrong here? How can I solve this?

Comment: What version of MPFR? Did you try using a full path instead of ../gmp-5.1.3? Do you really need --with-gmp-build at all?

Comment: mpfr-3.1.2, in ./configure fails when I didn't give --with-gmp-build, thats why I used it and then it succeeded, In make also it gave similar error like can't locate gmp.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the --with-gmp-build option (unless you know what you're doing) and don't use relative paths with configure. If you have installed GMP in directory DIR, just use --with-gmp=DIR.